# NSMutableData response string

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, nsmutabledata

I am trying to upload images to yFrog which is working just fine, but I want to grab just the URL from the response. When I use the `NSURLConnection` method

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[connection release];


NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData  
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// NSString *url = [webData valueForKey:@"mediaurl"];
NSLog(@"result: %@", responseString);
}
```

I get this as my response string

```
result: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsp stat="ok">
<mediaid>hszuhsp</mediaid>
<mediaurl>http://yfrog.com/hszuhsp</mediaurl>
</rsp>
```

As you can see in my blocked out code I tried to give my `NSMutableData` to give me the value of the key @"mediaurl" which just crashes. I think this should be relatively easy but for some reason I just can not figure out how to just grab  the URL out of the response. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid xml response.

If you need to parse only this response, you can iterate the `NSString`.

But if you have other response in xml format then the best approach is you are going to parse it using any XML parser.. :)

[Here is](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) how to choose your xml parser, and then you will search for tutorial accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know I had to parse this xml which in return was quite easy. I parse a few xmls already from my server so I have already encountered this. easy enough thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the `valueForKey` on the instance of `NSMutableData` class., you should use the XML parser to extract the value.