# Parsing Response value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml

I need to parse the below one in iPhone how can i?
Any one know please help me

```
<boolean xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</boolean>
```

Comment: [Have a look at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8921602/593709)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why we have the [NSXMLParser class.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: OK so maybe then it's not valid XML -- try NSScanner instead.